# Setup MonkeyRunner on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, monkeyrunner

I'd like to use MonkeyRunner. I've got a monkeyrunner.jar and import it into my project.
How can I use it now? Could you tell me what should I do step-by-step.
I've seen some code snippet on python, but I don't understand how can I use python in eclipse.

Comment: for eclipse you got pyDev. i can't recall exactly what's the right way to handle monkey runner python scripts but you can either install python and use IDLE not in eclipse, or use pydev, get it from the eclipse market or look in google for the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this link can help you how to use monkeyrunner in eclipse:

http://fclef.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/using-android-monkeyrunner-from-eclipse-in-windows/