# Use MonkeyRunner in an Android App?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setup MonkeyRunner on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556037/setup-monkeyrunner-on-android)

I need to be able to execute Android input events such as touch, multi touch, drag, etc. from an external source such as a Bluetooth device. I came across MonkeyRunner but I am not completely clear on how or if it would be useful to me. Would it be possible to run MonkeyRunner commands from Bluetooth input to simulate touch input?

If not MonkeyRunner, is there some other API that would prove useful for my needs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to be able to execute Android input events such as touch, multi touch, drag, etc. from an external source such as a Bluetooth device.

This is not possible, except via firmware modifications or *possibly* a rooted device.

> Would it be possible to run MonkeyRunner commands from Bluetooth input to simulate touch input?

No.

> If not MonkeyRunner, is there some other API that would prove useful for my needs?

No.

Comment: SO the only method is through adb on rooted devices? :(

Comment: The only ways to inject input events would be via firmware modifications or possibly rooted devices, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I can totally understand why getting events would be a huge security issue due to things like key loggers, but how would setting events be a major security issue? Eh... I suppose you could automate a script to   enable "run non-market apps" and then force install something malicious...

Grr, forcing people to root their devices would be a pain :\

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

go to the adb directory through a command prompt:

./adb -d shell monkey -p mypackagename -v 100                         //this runs 100 random touches on your device (switch -d for -e for emulator)

now make sure you have telnet installed if the above was successful do this:

./adb -d shell monkey -p mypackagename --port 1080 
and again

./adb -d forward tcp:1080 tcp:1080
lastly do this:

telnet localhost 1080

now that your connected you can run simple touch commands like this at the prompt:
tap 130 210
type 321
tap 140 283
press DEL

etc etc.